# C parameter set but not used

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I am using C to build a pebble watchface. I've been getting an error `parameter 'light_bitmap' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-parameter]`. The variable is however used in my function. I'm not sure what this message mean. Below is the code that I have:

In header declaration:

```c
void backlight_subscribe(GBitmap *light_bitmap, int start_hour, int end_hour);
```

In definition .c :

```c
void backlight_subscribe(GBitmap *light_bitmap, int start_hour, int end_hour) {
    int hour = get_current_hour();
    if((hour >= start_hour) || (hour < end_hour)) {
        accel_tap_service_subscribe(tap_handler);
        light_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_IMAGE_LIGHT_ON_ICON);
    } else {
        accel_tap_service_unsubscribe();
        light_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_IMAGE_LIGHT_OFF_ICON);
    }
}
```

and in main.c:

```c
static GBitmap *light_bitmap;
...
static void window_load(Window *window) {
     ...
     backlight_subscribe(light_bitmap, 22, 8);
     ...
}

static void init(void) {
    s_main_window = window_create();
    window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
        .load = window_load,
        .unload = window_unload,
    });
    window_stack_push(s_main_window, false); 
}

...

int main(void) {
    init();
    app_event_loop();
    deinit();
}
```

Full error message:

```
[16/28] c: src/accel_sensor.c -> build/src/accel_sensor.c.16.o
../src/accel_sensor.c: In function 'backlight_subscribe':
../src/accel_sensor.c:22:35: error: parameter 'light_bitmap' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-parameter]
 void backlight_subscribe(GBitmap *light_bitmap, int start_hour, int end_hour) {
                                   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/adminuser/pebble/pebble-app/watchface/build'
Build failed
```

Might anyone see where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "The variable is however used in my function." - No, it is not! The warning exactly tells you what your problem is! Where do you think you use it?

Comment: @Olaf I think I'm using it inside my if-else block

Comment: OT: `if((hour >= start_hour) || (hour < end_hour)) {` are you sure? it seems that you need the and operator `&&` in this case if you want to chack if the value is between start an end.

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, because I want to turn on the backlight during night time. So if i want to start at 10pm to 7am, then it'd be (hour >= 22) || (hour < 7).

Comment: @AlterMann  No worries :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as the error says, in your `backlight_subscribe` function, you're assigning a value to `light_bitmap` but you're not reading from it.  That means it's not being used.

In C, all parameters are pass by value.  So the value you assign to `light_bitmap` is visible only in that function.  If you're intending to change the variable you're passing in, you need to pass in the address of the variable in question, change the function to accept a pointer to that variable, then dereference the pointer when you assign to it:

```
void backlight_subscribe(GBitmap **light_bitmap, int start_hour, int end_hour) {
    int hour = get_current_hour();
    if((hour >= start_hour) || (hour < end_hour)) {
        accel_tap_service_subscribe(tap_handler);
        *light_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_IMAGE_LIGHT_ON_ICON);
    } else {
        accel_tap_service_unsubscribe();
        *light_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_IMAGE_LIGHT_OFF_ICON);
    }
}
```

Then you call the function like this:

```
backlight_subscribe(&light_bitmap, 22, 8);
```

As a side note, the function parameter `light_bitmap` is masking a global variable of the same name.  That can cause confusion, so try to avoid that.

Comment: Oh i see!! Thank you so much for the detailed explanations! I will accept this answer in 5 mins :)